# passing arrays in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am working on Grade Calculation. My problem here is if the length of string array is longer that int array it works skipping the last 2 grades. 
ex:

```
int[] unit = new int[] {1,-3,3,4};
string[] letter_grade = new string[] {"A", "B","B","W","D","F"};
```

but if length of int array longer than that of string array its not working its throwing error  Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
int[] unit = new int[] {1,-3,3,4,5,6,7};
string[] letter_grade = new string[] {"A", "B","B"};
```

so my question how do i make it work for both??

```
int length = unit.Length;
int no_units = length;
double totalGrade_Points = 0.0;
int totalno_units = 0;
totalGPA = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < unit.Length; i++)
{
  entrygot = findGpaListentry(letter_grade[i]); //Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  if (entrygot != null)
  {
     //some code calculation
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to access an index that is out of bounds. What's the question? (Note that `i` is in the range `[0, unit.length)` ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For array indexing you must have starting and stopping condition defined very well. For accessing two arrays either they must be equal or they are compared under certain valid conditions. Have a look at this:

```
for(int i=0;i<unit.length;i++){
entrygot = findGpaListentry(letter_grade[i]);// only if letter_grade is valid under all values of i i.e unit.length
}



// either you have to check as if;
    if(lenght_of_letter_grade < i-1)
    //then access 
    entrygot = findGpaListentry(letter_grade[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just check if the array item is null, because you would be out of the bounds of the array and you will get an exception before the null check occurs.

I would check the length of the array on each iteration...

```
for (int i = 0; i < unit.Length; i++)
{
    if (currentArray.Length < i - 1) { break; }
    // other code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, the number of elements will never be large hence performance wont be an issue. So I think you should be using a List instead of an array. With an array you will have to be insert checks each time some logic changes or you add other functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` loop is best for your scenerio.

```
    foreach (string s in letter_grade)
    {
      entrygot = findGpaListentry(s); 
      if (entrygot != null)
      {
         //some code calculation
      }
}
```